# efficiently set a large number of SciPy sparse matrix entries to zero

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to prune a large number of entries from a SciPy sparse matrix.
Currently I convert the matrix to the DOK format and individually assign
each entry to 0.

```
m = m.todok()
for i, j in pruneme:
  m[i,j] = 0
```

This is extremely slow.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: What format does `m` have normally?

Comment: @RolandW It starts of as a csr_matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set elements of CSR sparse arrays efficiently, as long as you do not add new nonzeros, simply by subscripting the array with tuples:

```
i, j = zip(*pruneme) # assuming that pruneme is a python list
m[i, j] = 0.
m.eliminate_zeros()
```

That should be much faster than constructing two arrays.